# Wrap multiple generic types into "generic namespace"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a code (React hook) that produces result with a bunch of complex types based on type arguments.

I want to provide a nice way to get all the related types from a single definition. I need all the types separately, because parts of the hook result are used in various places later.

Example (much simplified, my actual state manager code contains more generic arguments and output types, and the whole logic is pretty too complex for an SO post):

```
type FancyState<TState, TProps> = {
  MergedState: TState & TProps & {howMuchFancy: number};
  UpdateStateFunction: (state: TState, props: TProps) => void;
}

...
// declare generic arguments for my complex component
type FancyZoo = FancyState<{visitorCount: number}, {animals: Animal[]}>;

// use particular types from that component for various functions
const enjoyZoo = (zooState: FancyZoo['MergedState']) => { ... }
```

The above code works, but I don't like it, because:

- There is actually no object of type FancyState<...>, the type is declared only to extract desired types from its props. It feels like I'm not using the types how they were intended to be used.
- The syntax of accessing the type via `['']` feels weird too - it emphasizes I'm doing some type hacking here.

My idea is to do something like:

```
namespace FancyState<TState, TProps> {
  MergedState: TState & TProps & {howMuchFancy: number};
  UpdateStateFunction: (state: TState, props: TProps) => void;
}
namespace FancyZoo = FancyState<{visitorCount: number}, {animals: Animal[]}>;
const enjoyZoo = (zooState: FancyZoo.MergedState) => { ... }
```

but this syntax obviously does not work.

The question is: is there some better way to declare a group of types from one set of generic arguments, or is the first code snippet I posted the best available way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using types the way you're doing, but without generic namespaces or generic values (see [microsoft/TypeScript#15877](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15877) and the issues it links to) I don't think there's any *less* hacky solution.  Like, there's [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgr0BW), but it's worse.

Comment: yep, less ugly syntax in userland, but more hacky indeed :)